# ubuntu android ошибка "no such file or directory"

Tags: ubuntu, termux

я скачал термукс, установил ubuntu, а дальше установил gradle за этим гайдом https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-gradle-on-ubuntu-1804/

У меня выдает ошибку "`no such file or directory`" при использовании команды `cd /sdcard/` (возможно я описал проблему недостаточно подробно)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109496/discussion-on-question-by-diamianto-ubuntu-android--no-such-file-or-direc).

Comment: Ну спасибо. Я был так близок к ответу.

Comment: Можете в чате продолжить.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно писать с `storage`:

```bash
cd /storage/sdcard/
Или
cd /storage/sdcard0/
Или как у меня
cd /storage/emulated/0/
```